# Final vote to close doesn't update the UI

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, ios-app

I just gave the final vote to close on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403294/i-need-a-script-that-deletes-rows-after-a-certain-time-period) through the iOS app. As it doesn't show the number of close votes already, I was curious to see the status so I opened the question in Safari.

There I saw I was the final voter on that question, so the question got closed. The UI in the app wasn't updated though, like it does in the web site. When I refreshed the question manually, it did show the 'closed banner'.

I don't know whether this is considered a feature request or a bug, but either way: can this be added please?

Answer (score 4):

This will be fixed in 1.4.3.2.

We were calling `/questions/{id}/flags/add` (which returns the updated question) and just discarding the result.

Now we get the relevant updated fields (anything starting with `closed_`), applying it to the already loaded question and reloading the section.

Comment: Sounds good. Let me give it a try. Thanks.